# JSON serialization in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my sample asp.net MVC application , when ever user makes an AJAX call from browser , I would like to return data in JSON format mentioned below.

```
{
    "success":true,  // true or false
    "errorMessage":"", // errorMessage if there is any error
    "data": { } //this value will depend on the action method called
}
```

To return response in this format , I create an anonymous type in all action methods and then serialize it to JSON.

```
public ActionResult GetAuthors()
{
    List<BookStoreAdmin.ViewModels.Author> authors = BookStoreAdmin.BAL.Author.GetAuthors();
    var response = new { success = true, errors = "", data = authors };

    return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    // return Json(authors, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now , my question is there any better way or correct way to do this , instead of creating anonymous type in all action methods ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a generic model class and decorate its properties with `JsonPropertyAttribute`.

For example:

```
public class Response<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("errorMessage")]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use it instead of the anonymous object.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple method to keep it in one place ?

```
 public static class JsonExtensions
 {
     public static ActionResult ToJson(this object items)
     {
        var response = new { success = true, errors = "", data = items };

        return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
 }
```

and later

```
 public ActionResult GetAuthors()
{
    List<BookStoreAdmin.ViewModels.Author> authors = BookStoreAdmin.BAL.Author.GetAuthors();

    return authors.ToJson();
}
```

Plus either pass additional arguments to methods or create them per use case (success / error / etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can get better control if you create a class to return response.  You can can be sure about the structure and property names etc if you use class.

In your case if your `data` property can contain collection of different type then you can create a generic class as following.

```
public class Response<T>
{
    public bool Success {get;set;}
    public string ErrorMessage {get;set;}
    public T Data {get;set;}
}
```

And use it as following.

```
var response = new Response<List <BookStoreAdmin.ViewModels.Author>>();
response.Success = true;
response.ErrorMessage = "";
response.Data = authors; 

return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This way you can use this class to return resposne with collection of any type in Data property.